# foreach output to html table rows

Tags: php, html, массивы, list, foreach

Не могу обернуть вывод этого кода в таблицу html. Кусок массива:

```
array(2) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(7) "Success"
  ["extlist"]=>
  array(34) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["number"]=>
      string(3) "104"
      ["status"]=>
      string(10) "Registered"
      ["type"]=>
      string(3) "SIP"
      ["username"]=>
      string(23) "Маслов Денис"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      ["number"]=>
      string(3) "105"
      ["status"]=>
      string(10) "Registered"
      ["type"]=>
      string(3) "SIP"
      ["username"]=>
      string(23) "Семишин Юрий"
    }
```

Собственно код:

```
<table>
<tr>
   <th>Username</th>
   <th>DN</th>
   <th>status</th>
</tr>
$array = (json_decode($response, true));
//echo gettype($array) . "\n";
//var_dump($array);

//echo "Статус GET: {$array['status']}\n";

$arr_level_2 = $array['extlist'];

foreach ($arr_level_2 as $items) {
    foreach ($items as $value) {
    echo "<tr><td>$value</td></tr>";
    }
}

echo '</table></body></html>';
```

Весь вывод кидается в первую колонку Username, но мне надо что бы правильно рапределялся по всем трем. Я понимаю, что тут будет самое простое и очевидное решение, которое я не вижу. Пробовал использовать конструкцию типа:

```
 list($status, list($number, $status, $type, $username)) = arr_level_2('status', 0('number', 'username'));
```

но тут я не понял как определить второй массив который повторяется (0 и 1). Мне было бы интересно решить это через foreahc, но также и понять как в этом случае должен/может работать list(). Как декорировать переменные list() в html я понимаю )

То что мне требуется получилось сделать так:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  $username = $arr_level_2[$i]['username'];
  $number = $arr_level_2[$i]['number'];
  $status = $arr_level_2[$i]['status'];
  echo "<tr><td><a href=tel:$number>$number</a></td><td>$status</td><td>$username</td></tr>";
}
```

или как предложил @u_mulder:

```
foreach ($arr_level_2 as $item) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$item['number']}</td><td>{$item['status']}</td><td>{$item['Username']}</td></tr>";
}
```

Но тем не менее мне интересно как это можно решить через foreach и list

Comment: `echo "<tr><td>$items["number"]</td><td>$items["stauts"]</td><td>$items["Username"]</td></tr>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не надо придумывать сложности там, где их нет:

```
foreach ($arr_level_2 as $item) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$item['number']}</td><td>{$item['status']}</td><td>{$item['Username']}</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Да, так работает! А через list() не получиться выдернуть переменные?

Comment: А зачем генерировать новые переменные, если все что надо уже есть? К тому же `list` уже устаревшая конструкция. Массивы можно и без `list` распаковывать.

Comment: Если честно мне для развития и понимания, а переменные могут пригодиться где угодно, я понимаю что совсем не обязательно весь массив в них перегонять и что можно явно обратиться  явно к любому ключу массива.